# Asynchronous subscribe/notify instead synchronous HTTP in KNative Eventing

Tags: knative, knative-eventing

I am looking at [this KNative Eventing architecture diagram](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/)

[image]

And notice that the colour of arrows that goes into custom services is blue, that is the Services can only get called via HTTP protocol.

HTTP protocol is synchronous and also request/response oriented.

That seems to be contradiction to the Eventing nature, where we should aim at designing systems that are subscribe/notify oriented and asynchronous instead.

The source for the Service messages on the diagram is Kafka. That is a message broker whose primary purpose is to support asynchronous message delivery and subscribe/notify cases.

Why would KNative Eventing change that original channel transport nature from asynchronous subscribe/notify to synchronous request/response calling the services.

Is that true that the Services may only be called via HTTP in KNative Eventing (without custom work for developing own sidecars and service wrappers)? 
That looks to be a significant limitation.

If yes, why is that so? 
Is that done intentionally, or is it a temporary solution.
Why can't Service consume from channel (e.g. backed by Kafka) directly and why "channel subscriber" cannot be built into the Service Docker image wrapper or a sidecar.

Answer (score 0):

This is done on purpose and is one of the main advantages of Knative Eventing. Knative Eventing adds a layer of abstraction to asynchronous communication in a specific technology (e.g. Kafka), simplifying that communication to the familiar HTTP. Only from the point of service is the communication synchronous. Looking at the whole system, communication is asynchronous all the time and managed by a Broker or Channel centrally.

Comment: More on this in my Event Mesh talk https://youtu.be/2wTnWqT4oiw

Comment: Interesting presentation, thank you! I must disagree with some basic topic that you covered at the beginning though. [Database] transactions are not "rare" (you rely on them at the end of presentation) and they are far not only about "two things should happen together" (as majority of top Google search overviews simplify them to as well). Fortunately, "Database transactions" article on Wikipedia doesn't do that mistake. Thought it is obvious, the HTTP protocol alone cannot satisfy ACID guaranties inherently. If connection is lost in-flight the HTTP client cannot be sure whether

Comment: the request has been processed or not. In your talk you still rely on transactions heavily. 
 Your solution wouldn't be accurate/reliable if ETCD wouldn't provide ACID guarantees and if Kafka wouldn't provide transactional guarantees for publishing and consumption.
 You have essentially moved the difficulty of implementing a distributed transaction reliably from your code to ETCD.
 I also think that removing @Transactional from the code block and relacing one of the database calls with a remote service call is only going to break the code and the logic.

Comment: Switching to CQRS usually needs significant changes to the application logic and design. If we now replace transactional Kafka calls (that you invoke in the talk eventually as well) with HTTP calls the application consistency would break in certain failure modes (like transient network partitioning under heavy load).

Comment: But that's apparently exactly what KNative is doing: replacing (or at least injecting) reliable asynchronous message broker interface with unreliable synchronous protocol. Glad to discuss further, e.g. on Twitter :)